# Cycle in dependencies between targets 'StoreApp' and 'NotificationContentExtension'; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, frameworks, dependencies, swift4.1, xcode10

After updating Xcode 10.0 the following error occurs while building the project.

> Cycle in dependencies between targets 'StoreApp' and
>   'NotificationContentExtension'; building could produce unreliable results.
>   Cycle path: StoreApp → NotificationContentExtension → StoreApp Cycle
>   details: → Target 'StoreApp': LinkStoryboards ○ Target 'StoreApp'
>   has compile command with input
>
> ○ Target 'StoreApp' has target dependency on Target
>   'NotificationContentExtension' ○ That command depends on command in Target
>   'NotificationContentExtension': script phase “[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock”
>   → Target 'NotificationContentExtension' has target dependency on Target
>   'StoreApp' ○ That command depends on command in Target 'StoreApp':
>   script phase “[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock”

I have tried many different ways suggested in all other questions but none of them are working. Please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I got this too, just clean the build folder and it'll go away `Product -> Clean Build Folder`

Comment: tried it several time but not working.

Comment: You could also try installing Pods afterwards

Comment: For me, I hit this error after updating one of my dependencies, and Product -> Clean Build Folder solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue in the following ways:

First remove the Cocoapod from your project completely in the following way:

1. Delete the standalone files (Podfile Podfile.lock and your Pods
   directory)
2. Delete the generated xcworkspace
3. Open your xcodeproj file, delete the references to Pods.xcconfig and libPods.a (in the Frameworks group)
4. Under your Build Phases delete the Copy Pods Resources, Embed Pods Frameworks and Check Pods Manifest.lock phases.

After that uninstall Cocoapod from your computer completely:
To completely remove, issue the following commands:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-core
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

If you have multiple versions installed then uninstall them individually as follows:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.20.2
```

Run `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` to check whether cocoapods remained in your machine or not.

then restart your machine and reinstall Cocoapods into the machine into the following way:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

and finally integrate cocoapods with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone still searching for solution...

It worked for me in following steps:

1. Re-Install cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Update pods: `pod update`
3. Remove target dependencies from all targets under 'Build Phases >  Dependencies', like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a very similar issue. Turns out I had an `import StoreApp` command in one of the `NotificationContentExtension` files. Ensuring that you don't have circular `import` dependencies is important, instead you can just add files to be part of the other target that you want to use it in.